# Why does the MimeType of Media Recorder change when I start recording?

Tags: google-chrome, web-audio-api

The mimeType of the MediaRecorder changes after I start recording.  I have a JSFiddle which reproduces the behavior here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mattdeeds/5fvh3ac6/18/

I set the options to specify the pcm codec:

```
let options = {
  mimeType: "audio/webm;codec=pcm",
};
say('message0', MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType));
```

As expected:

- Supported: true

I create the MediaRecorder:

```
rec = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
say('message1', rec.mimeType);
```

As expected:

- Initial mimeType: audio/webm;codec=pcm

Now, I press "start" and "stop" to record a sample which executes this code:

```
rec.ondataavailable = e => {
   audioChunks.push(e.data);
   if (rec.state == "inactive"){
     say('message2', rec.mimeType);
     say('message3', e.data.type);
```

And what I get is not expected:

- Callback mimeType: audio/webm;codecs=opus
- Data mimeType: audio/webm;codecs=opus

I expected the MediaRecorder to use the codec I specified.  Per [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/#mediarecorder-api):

> 2.1.5 (constructor)
> Let recorder have a [[ConstrainedMimeType]] internal slot, initialized
> to the value of options’ mimeType member.

> 2.3.8 (start)
> If the [[ConstrainedMimeType]] slot specifies a media type, container, or codec, then
> constrain the configuration of recorder to the media type, container, and codec specified
> in the [[ConstrainedMimeType]] slot.

To me this pretty clearly states that if I request PCM which is supported, it will record in PCM.  Is this a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 1):

`codec` is not a valid Mime Type parameter.  You need to use `codecs` if you want it to be respected.

```
let options = {
  mimeType: "audio/webm;codecs=pcm",
};
```

With this change, your Fiddle works as expectd:

- Supported: true
- Initial mimeType: audio/webm;codecs=pcm
- Callback mimeType: audio/webm;codecs=pcm
- Data mimeType: audio/webm;codecs=pcm